# What are minimum permissions required to mount loop devices in Docker container?

Tags: docker

Trying to harden following to avoid using `--privileged`.

```
$ docker run --interactive --privileged --rm --tty --volume ${HOME}/shared:/shared ubuntu:20.04 bash

$ cd /shared

$ ls
disk.img

$ losetup --find --partscan --show disk.img
/dev/loop0

$ lsblk --all --noheadings --output "NAME,MAJ:MIN" --raw  /dev/loop0
loop0 7:1
loop0 259:0
loop0 259:1

$ ls /dev/loop0*

$ mknod /dev/loop0p2 b 259 1

$ mkdir -p root

$ mount /dev/loop0p2 root

$ umount /dev/loop0p2

$ losetup --detach /dev/loop0

$ rm /dev/loop0p2

$ exit
```